# Pyqgis and composer automatic print

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer

I am very new to PyQgis.

I have 3 shapefile containing a lot of information for each place (+5000), i wanto to automatic filter and zoom each one for a same key(field), and print in a template (qpt) refreshing the view to a filtered elements and change the title with the key.